# Twitter-Bootstrap button color on-loading state

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently working on a web project and I changed the Bootstrap's primary button color to orange. Now almost all button states work fine: active state, hover state, etc - **except the loading state**.

Once it enters the loading state, it **returns to its default color which is blue**.

I was searching on how to do it but seems I can't seem to find it. Can anyone help me out with this or if this question already exists, please redirect me to it. Preferably, I'd like to do it without javascript. Thanks!

Comment: In bootstrap, for warning they orange color is there by default. why you are changing btn-primary.. or better create seperate class with orange color..

Comment: hi @G.L.P, ignoring that one, for example, i changed it to pink perhaps... **is there a way to change the color of the loading-state of the button?** i'm overriding the bootstrap's btn-primary's color to suit my site's theme..

Comment: can you create a fiddle demo with what you tried sofar? & which version of bootstrap you are using?

Comment: Hi @G.L.P, i'm about to do it but at JSFiddle, i tested it and its working just fine. I missed the most important **!important** tag under the **active** state. (facepalm)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one rather can't be done without using JavaScript.

**First way, if you aren't afraid of JS**: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/deC37/452/)

HTML:

```
<button type="button" id="btn1" data-loading-text="Hm.." class="btn btn-primary">
  Loading state
</button>
```

**CSS**:

```
.btn-primary,
.btn-primary:hover,
.btn-primary:active {
    border: none;
    margin: 5px;
    background-color: #b2d025; /* here */
}
```

**JS**:

```
$("#btn1").click(function() {
    var $btn = $(this);
    $btn.button('loading');

    $(this).css('background-color','#b2d025'); /* and here */

    setTimeout(function () {
        $btn.button('reset');
    }, 1000);
});
```

**Second way (less js, more css, using !important)**: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/deC37/467/)

Comment: thanks for this dude. i totally missed **!important**.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Inline CSS

```
<button type="button" id="btn1" data-loading-text="Hm.." class="btn btn-primary" style="background-color:red">
  Loading state
</button>
```

> **Note :** This will gives your answer but `hover` and `active` effects will not work

Comment: I'm surprised, well done. "!important" would work as well then, right?

Comment: @MateuszKwaśniak Ya. what ever the line its hangs with inline code

Comment: Hi @Abdulla, this will only change the background color of the button on its normal state

Comment: Bro @MateuszKwaśniak, can you post an answer with the **!important** content so I can mark it as an answer? I totally forgot to put it and your comment reminded me of it. Thanks!

Comment: @acbadz, edited my post, check 2nd way I've described there

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using bootstrap's [customize](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/)
I think they have an option for changing the color of primary button. Look for btn-primary-color

Comment: I wasn't able to do it. And if i'll do it at my current stage in the development, I think I'll have lots to adjust and I don't have time for it. I know it's my fault, hehe. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `javascript` than you can try this..

```
.btn-primary,
.btn-primary:hover,
.btn-primary:focus,
.btn-primary:focus:hover {
    border: none;
    background-color: #b2d025;    
}
```

Hope this helps...